# Drawing lines as per screen coords in OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I have a 2D map that I have created in OpenGL-ES 2.0. Now I want to draw a scalebar.

As this will not be moved when the user pans the map, I need it to be drawn in screen coordinates somehow.

I could use some advice on how to accomplish something like this.

Comment: Consider using Normalized Device Coordinates, this is a coordinate system that ranges from [-1,1] in all 3 axes. No matter how your world or projection is defined, this coordinate space always has that range, a point at (-1,-1,-1) is always at the bottom-left and lies on the near plane. This coordinate space is the final step before the viewport transformation, which gets you to screen coordinates, so if you know your viewport dimensions you can easily do some simple math and work backwards into NDC.

Comment: The benefit of working in NDC is that you can use your existing shaders, just supply identity matrices for projection and modelview when you want to draw something that is defined in NDC. If you are thoroughly confused by all of this, I could try to write some pseudo code in answer form; but it will have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @AndonM.Coleman I have never tried this before so the more you can supply the better. Thanks appreciate your help!

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman happy enough to accept this as a answer if you like to place it in the answer

Comment: Sorry, I have been busy this week - hopefully the answer below provides enough information for you to solve this problem. If not, let me know and I will be happy to add more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, all you need to know is the dimensions of your viewport. Know that the viewport transformation is a very simple scale and bias operation, it effectively works like this:

```
 NDC    Screen
 ---    ------
-1.0 -> x          \_ X  (Passed using glViewport (...))
 1.0 -> x + width  /

-1.0 -> y          \_ Y  (Passed using glViewport (...))
 1.0 -> y + height /

-1.0 -> near       \_ Z  (Passed using glDepthRange (...))
 1.0 -> far        /
```

<sup>I apologize for the ugly ASCII art, I wish Stack Overflow supported LaTeX.</sup>

In other words, for X and Y, Normalized Device Coordinates (NDC) are scaled to fit within width and height many units, and the ***bottom-left-most*** point is defined by (x,y). For Z, which you probably do not care about, NDC is scaled from your defined near value to the defined far value.

What you want to do is **reverse** the viewport mapping operation; start with screenspace coordinates and work back into NDC.

- NDC<sub>X</sub> = (2.0 * (Screen<sub>X</sub> - Viewport<sub>X</sub>) / Viewport<sub>W</sub>) - 1.0;
- NDC<sub>Y</sub> = (2.0 * (Screen<sub>Y</sub> - Viewport<sub>Y</sub>) / Viewport<sub>H</sub>) - 1.0;

This should provide you with all the necessary steps to produce NDC<sub>(X,Y)</sub> coordinates from Screen<sub>(X,Y)</sub>. Once you have NDC coordinates, you can pass them directly to your shaders using identity matrices for Model, View and Projection.

<sub>The alternative is to skip all of this and use an orthographic projection matrix that defines a 1:1 mapping between projection and window (another name for screenspace) coordinates, but I think it is better to teach NDC and how the viewport mapping works in the long run :)</sub>